# Will a few weeks of exposure to the weather damage cementboard?

Tags: concrete

I am getting ready to put Durock on my outdoor grill area. I am wrapping it with stone but it will be a few weeks before the stone comes in. Will the rain damage the cement board in any way or should I wait until the stone comes in? Was wanting to start using the grill if the weather will not hurt anything.

Answer (score 3):

I would wrap it in plastic.  The rain won't intrinsically hurt it but mud and other particles could ruin some of the ability for the thinset to adhere.

Comment: Or prime rib grease.

Comment: @isherwood - prime rib grease is a known bonding agent.  Binds directly to my gut.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure the following is just for the money, but here's the cut-n-paste answer: [Storage Conditions](https://www.usg.com/content/dam/USG_Marketing_Communications/united_states/product_promotional_materials/finished_assets/storage-and-handling-WB2333.pdf)

> Protecting building materials from water and weather elements is important. Exposure to the weather not only damages building materials by moisture intrusion, but it also causes other harm not immediately obvious.
>
> Examples include:
>
> – Moisture can affect the bond of the face paper to the gypsum core causing problems during application and finishing.
>
> – Ultraviolet (UV) exposure from sunlight will ruin the ability of plaster base panels (blue board) to act as a substrate for some veneer plasters.
>
> If building materials are left unprotected from moisture before, during or after construction, conditions can become favorable for mold and mildew growth. It is necessary to eliminate all sources of moisture immediately.
>
> Although board products are very heavy, high winds across the flat surfaces of the board can provide “lift” just as with an airplane wing, and thus wind can send heavy pieces of gypsum wallboard flying through the air causing damage and serious injuries.
>
> For more information, contact the Gypsum Association at 202-289-5440 and request Handling Gypsum Board (GA801-93).
>
> Trademarks
>
> The following trademarks used herein are owned by United States Gypsum or a related company: DUROCK, FIBEROCK, IMPERIAL, SHEETROCK.
>
> Notice
>
> We shall not be liable for incidental and consequential damages, directly or indirectly sustained, nor for any loss